# ES6 Do importing same component multiple times across an SPA have performance issues?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component

Background - Am new to working with ES6 & SPAs (Single Page Applications) and have previously worked mainly on PHP based applications.

Creating a Vue based SPA and in it we create re-usable components and import them wherever needed. A couple of times now, I've written code that `import`(s) a few components and one of those components in-turn imports a component that is used by the first one. Now ignore the last line and I'll try to explain this with pseudocode -

```
****
File name: main-component.vue
****

...
import compA from sub-component-a.vue
import compB from sub-component-b.vue
import apiCompA from api-component-a.vue
...

****
File name: sub-component-a.vue
****

...
import compC from sub-component-c.vue
import apiCompA from api-component-a.vue
...
```

Now when the main component is loaded `api-component-a.vue` is imported twice (atleast that's what I think). Thus the confusion.

Is this something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working because it is based on nodejs `require` and is something you can do just because you are compiling your js. During compilation every module/component will get it's own IIFE and `import` means components are simply injected into other modules/components. There won't be any performance issues if you use vue cli or webpack, since every module will only be included one time in the final compiled code.

Comment: is it supposed to be IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression) or IFFE. When I search for **js IFFE**, Google says **Did you mean: js _IIFE_** :)

Answer (score 6):

Reusing the same shared module in multiple places is the whole point of modules. No matter how often you import a module, it is only loaded and evaluated once.

There is nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: It would be nice to have some evidence to back this up - I'd imagine the same - but it's not necessarily the case

Comment: @NoelEvans You can read the design documents of modules or the respective part of the spec, but I thought it would be obvious enough not to require a citation. What do you mean by "*it's not necessarily the case*"?

Comment: The compiled JS is rendered by engines in one of many browsers. If Chrome reads the same import twice, does it dismiss the loading of the referenced module for a second time? I'd sure like to hope so but the answer is is only reached with empirics - source code citation or statistics showing that importing the same (large) module 100 times makes no difference to a page load compared to a single import.

Comment: @NoelEvans Yes, if multiple import specifiers resolve to the same url, that *one* referenced module is neither loaded nor executed twice. You don't need anecdotal evidence for that, just read the spec.